# Using javascript to load/unhide images one at a time?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make what I thought would be a simple function. All I am trying to do is load images, I have 7 of them inserted into my HTML body like so  to where they don't show on page load. But then I am wanting them to load them on to the page 1 by 1 (so 1 will load every second). Like I wrote above, I have an id attribute in each image tag that will correspond to the image names I have in the array below. Here is my code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {
        var images = ["imt","drpepper","principal","grinnell","keyot","vonmaur","thanks"];
        for (i=0; i<images.length;i++){
            var image = document.getElementById(images[i]);
            setTimeout(function(){image.style.visibility = "visible";}, 1000);  
        }
    }
  </script>
```

I have been working on this for hours. I can not understand why it is not working. Please help!

Comment: Can you throw that code into http://jsfiddle.net/ with your HTML so we can see it in action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/d5tc0cse/)***

The problem with using a variable inside of a setTimeout like that is that it will use the last value of `i`. The result is that only your last image is shown. In order to make it store the value of `i`, you need to close over that value. This can be done with an immediately executing function expression

```
for (var i=0; i<images.length;i++){
 (function(i){
  var image = document.getElementById(images[i]);
  setTimeout(function(){
    image.style.visibility = "visible";
  }, 1000);  
 })(i)
}
```

Comment: this is what worked for me, except to get them to display one by one i had to made the time argument 1000*i. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what's wrong here and its boils down to understanding closures...But I may have misconstrued your question. You talk about loading images and that to me implies that you are generating new images dynamically (via `new Image()`) and then setting their `src` attribute dynamically (thereby causing the HTTP request to festch them). That's a different matter I am going to answer with the assumption that your problem is due to closures.

The problem being that when the 1000 ms trigger points fires for the first time the value of `image` will be the last element fetched based on the last ID stringname in the array. You need this code instead:

```
...other code same as before
for (i=0; i<images.length;i++){
    (function() {
        var image = document.getElementById(images[i]);
        setTimeout(function(){image.style.visibility = "visible";}, 1000); 
    })();
}
...other code same as before
```